# Identify and disable(readonly) particular section of word document(.docx) using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a requirement of identifying a particular part or section of a word document having extension .docx and disabled it so that other users aren't able to modify it. What is the best api for it in java. Please provide a complete meaningful example, including details about jars and all. Thanks in advance....

Comment: It would be nice if you can do this in word itself once document is created , https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/508-word-lock-parts-of-document.html , No need to specifically do through programming

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Apache POI Library](https://poi.apache.org/). I have been able to read in word documents (.docx) as a `byte[]` and lock certain sections of the file for editing.  In the example below, it assumes that bookmarks are placed within the document so specify which sections should be locked, and which should be left as editable.

```
//Open word document with Apache POI
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wordDoc);
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);

    //Collect all Bookmarks from the document
    List<Bookmark> bookmarks = getBookmarks(document);

    //Collect all editable sections from the document
    List<EditableSection> editableSections = getEditableSections(bookmarks);

    //NOW MARK THE SECTIONS IN THE DOCUMENT WHICH ARE EDITABLE
    Random random = new Random();
    String randomId = Integer.toString(random.nextInt(1000000000));

    for(EditableSection section: editableSections)
    {
        CTPermStart permStart = section.getStart().getCTP().addNewPermStart();
        permStart.setEdGrp(STEdGrp.EVERYONE);
        permStart.setId(randomId);

        CTPerm permEnd = section.getEnd().getCTP().addNewPermEnd();
        permEnd.setId(randomId);
    }

    //Enforce the readonly protection everywhere except where it was marked safe
    document.enforceReadonlyProtection(wordProtectPassword, HashAlgorithm.md5);

    ByteArrayOutputStream res = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    document.write(res);
    return res.toByteArray();


public class EditableSection {

    private XWPFParagraph start;
    private XWPFParagraph end;

    public EditableSection(XWPFParagraph start, XWPFParagraph end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public XWPFParagraph getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(XWPFParagraph start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public XWPFParagraph getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(XWPFParagraph end) {
        this.end = end;
    }
}

public class Bookmark {

    private String bookmark;
    private XWPFParagraph paragraph;

    public Bookmark(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String bookmark) {
        this.paragraph = paragraph;
        this.bookmark = bookmark;
    }

    public String getBookmark() {
        return bookmark;
    }

    public void setBookmark(String bookmark) {
        this.bookmark = bookmark;
    }

    public XWPFParagraph getParagraph() {
        return paragraph;
    }

    public void setParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
        this.paragraph = paragraph;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know :)